# How can I mask every element except each nth, in an iterator?

Tags: python, numpy, mask

I am trying to create a masked array (or at least NaN filled) that provides the values only at the nth (8th in the example) place. The array should be the same length as the original.

Is there a less ridiculous way to do this?

```
b = np.array([[i for i in 7*[np.nan] + [val]] for val in a[::8]]).flatten()[7:]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use slice assignment:

```
>>> a
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
       34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50,
       51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63])
>>> b = numpy.array([numpy.NaN] * len(a))
>>> b[::8] = a[::8]
>>> b
array([  0.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,   8.,  nan,  nan,
        nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  16.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,
        nan,  nan,  24.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  32.,
        nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  40.,  nan,  nan,  nan,
        nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  48.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,
        nan,  56.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generator expression to create the "list" more elegantly.

```
def val_only_on_nth(n, limit):
    for v in xrange(limit):
        if v%n == 0:
            yield v
        else:
            yield np.NaN
```

and use np.from_iter to convert it into an np array

```
b = np.fromiter(val_only_on_nth(8,64))
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work in the general case:

```
n=8
a=np.random.random((64,))   # example random array to mask
a[np.arange(0,len(a))%n!=0]=np.nan


array([ 0.68756737,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,  0.68577462,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,  0.89002182,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,  0.26135927,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,  0.66857456,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
        0.39230499,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,  0.85367809,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,  0.48642591,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan])
```